# How can I run UPDATE and INSERT statements from an SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a single statement, which

- returns 'InsufficentFunds' when the user has no money
- returns 'AlreadyOwns' when the user already has the item
- returns 'Success' when none of the criteria above is met and inserts/updates the data into the db

I can do almost everything using this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM known_packages WHERE playerid = 1 AND packageid = 1) > 0 THEN 'AlreadyOwns' WHEN 100 > balance THEN 'InsufficientFunds' ELSE 'Success' END FROM players WHERE playerid = 1;
```

The only problem is that using this it seems like I cannot run the insert/update statements. I could just get the response and send out another query for the insert/update statements, but it would be awesome if this could be done with a single statement.

Comment: This really asks for a stored procedure.

Comment: `insert into your_table select ...` and `update your_table set col1 = (select ...) where ...`

Comment: I know I could use a stored procedure, but a solution without stored procedures would be awesome.

Comment: You can insert, you can update, but you cannot do those things *and* return data from them.

Comment: I have no idea what would be awsome about a select statement that does inserts and updates.